# How can I get the byte size of std::wstring?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, size, wstring

I am using `std::wstring` as my Unicode style string. Now I want to get the 
byte size of a `wstring`. 
If I use `size()` method of `wstring`, I just get the total number of chars 
in my `wstring`. But the byte should be size() * 2. 
Is there an official way to get this byte size? I don't want to use 
size() * 2 in my program.....

I want to use in `RegSetValueExW` as last parameter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `str.size() * sizeof(wchar_t)` or equivalent.

In fact, I can't think of any other platform besides Windows that has 2-byte `wchar_t`, 4 bytes is far more common.

Comment: If you're setting a REG_SZ using RegSetValueExW, you'll want to also add a character for the null terminator: `(str.size() + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)`

Answer (score 9):

Why not :

```
( str.size() * sizeof(wchar_t) ) ;
```

Or :

```
( str.size() * sizeof(std::wstring::traits_type::char_type) ) ;
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, no need to divide by it.

Comment: Yes in any standard compliant compiler sizeof(char) == 1, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::wstring s = L"Howdy, world!";
//...
std::size_t bytes_count = s.size() * sizeof s[0];
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `wcslen` function

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx

Linux: http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcslen

Comment: That returns number of chars, not the number of bytes, and requires a C-Style pointer, not a std::w/string.